# Знаки препинания: "Самое главное, определиться, куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать"

Tags: пунктуация

Читаю предложение на одном из интернет-ресурсов.
**"Самое главное, определиться, куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать."**
Может, лучше поставить знаки вот так: "Самое главное- определиться куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать"?

Answer (score 1):

Не нравится мне сочетание САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ. Не может быть **главное** САМЫМ!

***Самое главное - определиться, куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать.*** 
Между подлежащим ГЛАВНОЕ  (прилагательное в роли существительного)  и **сказуемым в форме инфинитива** ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬСЯ ставится **тире** по обычному правилу постановки тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. После главного предложения "Самое главное - определиться..."с помощью союзных слов КУДА и КАКОЙ присоединяется придаточное предложение, поэтому перед словом КУДА необходима запятая.

Comment: Что является чем? Задайте этот вопрос применительно к нашему примеру. "Определиться (далее по тексту)... является самым главным". Следовательно, подлежащее в примере - "определиться", а сказуемое - "самое главное" (превосходная степень прилагательного - это один член предложения).

Comment: Конечно, если бы предложение выглядело так: "Определиться - самое главное...", подлежащим было бы слово "определиться", сказуемое "самое главное". Но у нас другой случай.

Comment: ПАС ЛОПАТИНА: 12. Тире ставится при выражении и подлежащего, и сказуемого (или только подлежащего, или только сказуемого) инфинитивом: В этом городе знать три языка — ненужная роскошь (Ч.); Hu с чем не сравнимое чувство — слышать их [грачей] в первый раз после шестимесячной зимней смерти! (Бун.).

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы правы. Вместо тире можно подставить "это", а после "определиться" запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Что мы имеем? Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточной изъяснительной частью. В главном предложении подлежащее выражено инфинитивом (*определиться*), а сказуемое  - составное именное (*самое главное*). Следовательно, нужно ставить тире. После глагола **определиться**, обозначающего мыслительную деятельность (определиться = 'понять'), следует придаточная изъяснительная часть (понять что? определиться с чем?). Поэтому после инфинитива нужна запятая. Таким образом, знаки препинания в вашем примере такие: "Самое главное - определиться, куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать".

Comment: Я думал, что придаточная часть,состоящая из одного слова, не выделяется и запятой после слова "куда" не требуется..
Но спасибо за ответ)

Comment: ernest00,здесь придаточное предложение состоит вовсе НЕ из одного слова: "...куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать". Это предложение с однородными обстоятельствами КУДА, В КАКОЙ ВУЗ. Сказуемое "подавать".