# Знаки препинания при словосочетании "и самое главное"

Tags: пунктуация

Как расставить знаки препинания:

**Все эти средства доступны и самое главное – эффективны.**

Answer (score 1):

**Все эти средства доступны и, самое главное, эффективны.**

Здесь самое главное — вводное словосочетание, оно выделяется запятыми (см. примеры ниже)

Должен заметить, "самое главное" — плеоназм (главное — оно одно и не делится на просто главное и самое главное). Об этом писала в своих ответах @ЕкатеринаКаштанова ([Знаки препинания: "Самое главное, определиться, куда, в какой ВУЗ их подавать"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%92%D0%A3%D0%97-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C))

Однако в Нацкорпусе есть немало примеров его употребления (так сложилось):

Создаются каналы на YouTube, на других видеосервисах, и, если их удается интегрировать в две популярные среди молодежи социальные сети ― Instagram и «Вконтакте», при этом эффективно работая с артистом и его контентом **и, самое главное,** с подписчиками его аккаунтов, можно добиваться очень хороших результатов. [Вячеслав Суриков, Сергей Балдин. Невидимая сторона шоу-бизнеса // «Эксперт», 2015]

Сближение двух стран обусловлено не только желанием России получить китайских инвесторов, но и тем, что у Пекина и Москвы близкие взгляды на международную ситуацию **и, самое главное,** на судьбу контролируемых американцами институтов глобального управления. [коллективный. Огненные объятия Дракона // «Эксперт

Монастыри всегда хранили традиции: книжные, уставные **и, самое главное,** традиции духовного делания. [Н. Зяблицина. Велегласно, косно, сладкопевно. Разговор с регентом (2009) // Журнал Московской Патриархии № 1, 2010, 2010]